# SIF 2.0.0 on SC 9.0.2 - "The operation is on user root store and UI is not allowed"

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

After the release of SIF 2.0.0, an automated SC 9.0.x script began failing with the error:

> The operation is on user root store and UI is not allowed.

This error occurs during the execution of `xconnect-createcert.json`, which is included in the SC On-Prem WDP package > Configuration Files zip.

After inspecting `xconnect-createcert.json`, I noticed that it specifies `CurrentUser` as the Store Location for the cert.

My script runs as the `System` user account as part of the DSC (Desired State Configuration) execution on a VM created via an Azure ARM template.

If I explicitly request SIF 1.2.1, the certificate is installed properly. Strangely, with 1.2.1, the cert is installed in the `LocalMachine` store. I suspect SIF 1.2.1 has some additional code to ensure this Store Location is used.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As discussed on the #sif Sitecore Slack channel, when using vanilla SC WDP configs the SIF version *does* have a dependency on the installed SC version.

- SIF 2.0.0 = SC 9.1
- SIF 1.2.1 = SC 9.0.x

There are two ways to solve the problem outlined above.

#### 1) Define SIF Version Explicitly

If installing SIF for the first time via PowershellGallery:

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -Repository SitecoreGallery -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
```

If SIF 2.0.0 was previously installed, you will need to first uninstall then reinstall with the proper version:

```
Uninstall-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework
```

#### 2) Modify Config Files Prior to Installation

To use SIF 2.0.0 to install SC 9.0.x...

**Modify `xconnect-createcert.json`**

1. Find the `CreateRootCert` task
2. Change the `StoreLocation` from `CurrentUser` to `LocalMachine`

**Modify `xconnect-solr.json` and `sitecore-solr.json`**

1. Find the `CreateCores` task in each file
2. Change the `"Name"` attribute in Params > Action to lowercase `"name"`

*Original Example*

`{ "Action": "Create", "Address": "[parameter('SolrUrl')]", "Arguments": { "Name": "[variable('Core.Name')]" } },`

*Updated*

`{ "Action": "Create", "Address": "[parameter('SolrUrl')]", "Arguments": { "name": "[variable('Core.Name')]" } },`

Comment: This worked a treat. Major pain to have to uninstall and change SIF versions when moving between projects. Thanks for posting this @jrap