# Install-SitecoreConfiguration xconnect-solr.json - Error Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask : Missing required parameter: name

Tags: solr, configuration, xconnect, installation

**What:**

I am trying to install sitecore XP1 architecture. I already have a signed certificate. My issue comes when I try to configure sitecore on my solr. Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219. SOLR 6.6.4. Windows server 2016. JRE 1.8.0_191

**What I did :**

1. Installed iis
2. Installed Web Platform Installer
3. Installed Java JRE (and add java_home to the Environment Variables)
4. Installed SOLR (and created a service with NSSM to run solr at boot time)
5. Installed certificate with keytool.exe // configure solr.in.cmd // bind iis with the certificate
6. Installed FrameWork Sitecore from MyGet

Until here everything is working fine. The service is running and I can connect to my SOLR in HTTPS.

**Issue :** 
When I run this command

```
$solrParams =
@{
    Path = "C:\Sitecore\installer\config\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = "https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr"    
    SolrRoot = "C:\Sitecore\solr-6.6.4"
    SolrService = "solr"
    CorePrefix = "sc_pprd"
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose
```

I can see everything is going great without any warning then the CreateCores step fail:

```
[------------------------------------------------------ CreateCores [1] : ManageSolrCore -------------------------------------------------------]
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Requesting" on target "https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr".
[CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr
VERBOSE: GET https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr with 0-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 13592-byte response of content type text/html;charset=utf-8
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask -Address https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr -Action Create" on target "https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr".
[CreateCores [1]]:[SolrCore] Performing Create on https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr

VERBOSE: Updating Solr: Uri => 'https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr/admin/cores?action=Create&Name=sc_pprd_xdb&wt=json'
VERBOSE: GET https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr/admin/cores?action=Create&Name=sc_pprd_xdb&wt=json with 0-byte payload
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Missing required parameter: name
At C:\Sitecore\installer\config\solr_instal_pprd.ps1:10 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:15
Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask : Missing required parameter: name
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask
```

I must say that for the moment no link is set between the SOLR server and the SQL server. I can't understand why and where I should add an argument name.

Comment: can you open in browser : https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr/? is it secured connection ? I am not sure if Solr 6.6.4 is compatible with 9.0.1. Recommended version is 6.6.2 https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

Comment: Yes I can open it in a browser and the connection is secure. I know it works with solr 6.6.4 and sc 9.0.1 as we already have an environment working with the same version of OS and apps.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe you are facing a problem with the SitecoreInstallationFramework version?

Sitecore 9.0.X requires 1.2.1:

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
```

Sitecore.9.1.0 requires 2.0.0:

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.0.0
```

Sitecore.9.1.1 requires 2.1.0:

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.1.0
```

Sitecore.9.2.0 requires 2.1.0:

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.1.0
```

Sitecore.9.3.0 requires 2.2.0:

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.2.0
```

Sitecore.10.0.0 requires 2.3.0:

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.3.0
```

Comment: No I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 and I have used the exact same solr script on many different servers in the past. I am using SIF 1.2.1 and it's giving me that error now which it never did before.

Comment: I was wrong. I found out that I actually did have 2.0.0 SIF installed and when I uninstalled it and installed the 1.2.1 version it worked. Thanks for this answer DarkStaR

Comment: Switching to 1.2.1 is the quickest fix. Otherwise there are a few additional steps to run 9.0.x on SIF 2.0.0: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15334/sif-2-0-0-on-sc-9-0-2-the-operation-is-on-user-root-store-and-ui-is-not-allow

Comment: Thanks I removed the module then reinstalled the version 1.2.1 and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 14):

Modify `xconnect-solr.json` and `sitecore-solr.json`

Find the CreateCores task in each file
Change the `Name` attribute in `Params > Action` to lowercase `name`

**Original Script**

```
{ "Action": "Create", "Address": "[parameter('SolrUrl')]", "Arguments": { "Name": "[variable('Core.Name')]" } },
```

**Updated Script**

```
{ "Action": "Create", "Address": "[parameter('SolrUrl')]", "Arguments": { "name": "[variable('Core.Name')]" } },
```

Comment: Only answer that actually solved this error

Comment: Semi-related: If you see the same error during commerce installation, you can perform an equivalent change in `SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.4.7\Configuration\Commerce\Solr\sitecore-commerce-solr.json`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue and it's because of this line in the sitecore script

```
VERBOSE: Updating Solr: Uri => 'https://blabla.bla.com:8984/solr/admin/cores?action=Create&Name=sc_pprd_xdb&wt=json'
```

The problem is that the "Name" paramter in the URI they are executing has a capital "N". If you try to invoke that same URI in a browser with a lowercase "n" it works.

The problem I am facing now is how to run this script without that error happening. Is this something that Sitecore has to change in their SIF code?

Comment: Thanks to DarkStaR I found out that this error happens when you're using Sitecore 9.0.X and trying to run SIF version 2.0.0. You need to install version 1.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) It was "just" as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error today and on investigation found another issue as the root cause. Logging it here for if someone else faces the same issue.

The root cause was SOLR was running out of the JVM. The same can be validated by browsing the SOLR URI. A message of the error is displayed there. Same can also be found in the logs of SOLR.